# Laravel select quizzes belonging to current user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently working on a quiz application in laravel 5.6 and am attempting to fetch all quizzes that belong to the current authenticated user.

I have three tables:

`users`
`quizzes`
`user_quizzes`

The `quizzes` table simply holds all the information relating to the quiz such as:

```
 - id
 - quiz_name
 - quiz_description
 - active
 - total_plays
 - created_at
 - updated_at
```

The users table is just the laravel default with minor changes:

```
 - id
 - username
 - email
 - password
 - remember_token
 - created_at
 - updated_at
```

The `user_quizzes` table holds two fields (both foreign keys): `user_id` and `quiz_id`.

At the moment it outputs ALL the quizzes, rather than just ones belonging to the current user.

In my `QuizController` I have:

```
$quizzes = Quiz::find(Auth::user()->id)->with('user')->get();
```

And my `QuizModel`:

```
class Quiz extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'quizzes';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }
}
```

Finally the `UserModel` contains:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function activation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Activation');
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Profile');
    }

    public function quizzes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Quiz');
    }
}
```

I have also tried using the `DB facade` with joins but received the same output (all quizzes returned, not just ones belonging to the current user). Here is what I did for that, just for reference:

```
$quizzes = DB::table('user_quizzes')
                        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_quizzes.user_id')
                        ->join('quizzes', 'quizzes.id', '=', 'user_quizzes.quiz_id')
                        ->get();
```

I feel like I am making a silly mistake, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change Eloquent relationship in the Model.

```
class User extends Model {
    public function quizzes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Quiz::class, 'user_quizzes','user_id', 'quiz_id');
    }
}
```

Same with Quiz Model

```
class Quiz extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'quizzes';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_quizzes','quiz_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

DB facade you're doing incorrectly.
You want to fetch all quizzes for the users so you need to query quizzes table like this.

```
DB::table('quizzes')->leftJoin('user_quizzes', 'user_quizzes.quiz_id', 'quizzes.id')->join('users', 'user_quizzes.user_id', 'user_id')->where('users.id', $USER_ID)->get();
```